# Getting error while checking for npm version post installing Node.js in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-version

Getting the following error while checking for `npm` version using Windows PowerShell.

```
Program 'npm.cmd' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At line:1
char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm -v
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The nodejs installer will not automatically add the installation directory to the `PATH`, so anything command line will not know where to look. Find the directory containing npm (usually under `/Program Files/NodeJS/...`), and add it manually to the PATH.

Comment: I tried creating new environment variables like this...                     
NODESJS_HOME= C:\Program Files\nodejs
NODESJS_MODULES=C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules
NODEJS_NPM =C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm                              
  Can this cause any problem?

Comment: That's well and good, but `PATH` is the one that matter here.

Comment: tried addind this path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin under PATH in environment variable, but still getting the same error. I think this error is OS related.

Comment: Unfortunately just user error (and lack of a proper installer): you need to add the folder that _contains_ `npm` (and in effect, contains `node_modules`). AKA you should be adding: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\\`